# Using Regex to validate a parameter using Python library click?

Tags: python, python-click

I'm using click for parsing command line argument https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/

```
import click
@click.option('-n', '--name', required=True, type=str, help='...')
def create(name: str):
```

I want to use regular express to make sure the name matching a particular pattern. How to do it using click?

Answer (score 8):

Use `callback`.

```
def open_url(ctx, param, value):
    if re.match('...', value):
        return value
    else:
        raise click.BadParameter('.....')

@click.command()
@click.option('--url', callback=open_url)
def cli(url, fp=None):
```